# Why the different colours for SACK markers in Wireshark's tcptrace graph?

Tags: wireshark

Wireshark's `tcptrace` time sequence graph shows a good deal of information, but I cannot find a document that spells out exactly what it all means. It's broadly similar to the [original `tcptrace`](https://www.tcptrace.org) except for the colour scheme and a few missing elements:

- Blue I-beams indicate packets sent (cf. white and red arrows in `tcptrace`; Wireshark does not show retransmissions differently)
- A green line indicating the calculated receive window (cf. a yellow line in `tcptrace`)
- A brown line indicating the acked sequence number, with little ticks indicating a received ACK that didn't ack anything new (cf. a green line in `tcptrace`)
- SACKs are shown as red or brown vertical lines (cf. purple lines in `tcptrace`)
- Special packets (SYNs, FINs etc) are not shown specially.

Here is an example showing all of these features.

[image: example Wireshark tcptrace graph]

However, I cannot see any obvious difference between the red and brown SACKs; it seems that the highest SACK is coloured red and the lower ones are brown, but this doesn't seem to me to be something worth distinguishing with different colours so I think I am missing something. What is the real reason for the two different SACK colours?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does seem to be simply that the first (highest-numbered) SACK range is plotted differently from the rest. From [the source](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=ui/qt/tcp_stream_dialog.cpp;hb=fcf787b408dd812f14d68aa2209f803f3e2d9247#l859) noting in particular the branch on `i == 0`:

```
 854             // add SACK segments to sack, sack2, and selectable packet graph
 855             for (int i = 0; i < seg->num_sack_ranges; ++i) {
 856                 double half = seg->sack_right_edge[i] - seg->sack_left_edge[i];
 857                 half = half/2.0;
 858                 double center = seg->sack_left_edge[i] - seq_offset_ + half;
 859                 if (i == 0) {
 860                     sack_time.append(ts);
 861                     sack_center.append(center);
 862                     sack_span.append(half);
 863                     if (allow_sack_select) {
 864                         pkt_time.append(ts);
 865                         pkt_seqnums.append(center);
 866                     }
 867                 } else {
 868                     sack2_time.append(ts);
 869                     sack2_center.append(center);
 870                     sack2_span.append(half);
 871                 }
 872             }
```

Elsewhere in the same source file we see the `sack2` data being plotted with a different colour from the `sack` data, `tango_scarlet_red_6` vs `tango_scarlet_red_4` respectively.